# What does my cpu do when it is labeled as "system cpu"?

Tags: linux, profiling, cpu

My code often use a lot of "system cpu" (on ubuntu).

I understand that this means that the cpu is doing something else than actually running my code. I heard it can for instance input/ouput management.

I have two questions:

1) Can I have a more exhaustive list of what the cpu could be doing when it's on "system cpu"?

2) When I run a specific program, is there a way to identify, what the system cpu is doing on this run? (some kind of "system cpu" profiling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your CPU is in system state, that's because system calls are being executed. These system calls are for example I/Os (display, network, files), or memory (allocation, ...).

You can run your program using strace to get a verbose display of what system calls are currently executed by your program.